# how to do WHERE a*b = param1 in NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate

I need to create a query in NHibernate that would search for a product of two columns, like this:

WHERE a*b = param1

leaving efficiency aside (assume I have little rows or actual query will have extra conditions that will exploit some indexes) how do I do it in NHibernate? Preferably the solution should work with DetachedCriteria. I know I could use native SQL with Expression.Sql() but is there any other, better, way? Can I do this in HQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with HQL or Expression.Sql as you mentioned. HQL supports many different SQL expressions; see [this section](http://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/nhibernate/1.2/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-expressions).

For example:

```
session.CreateQuery("from test t where t.a * t.b = 4").List();
```